# Can I expect my status at an international bank to travel with me?

Tags: international

I have a Citigold account in Taiwan where I meet the local requirements for that status. Is it reasonable to expect Citibank in the US to open a Citigold account for me there as well just based off of me having the status in Taiwan despite not meeting the requirement in the US? Is it something I have to get my account manager in Taiwan to do (they aren't really sure how the American bank operates) or is it something I'd have to call Citibank in the US to do for me (there doesn't seem to be an option on their website)?

I want it to be able to transfer money back and forth for free, and having to meet an additional requirement or pay a fee to maintain the American account seems to defeat the purpose.

Or in other words, for international banks, is it typical to expect my status to travel with me to that bank in other countries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no typical answer for this.

For my local Citibank, the relationship manager said that I must maintain Citigold minimum for both jurisdictions, but I can always downgrade / close the local account. The relationship manager will remotely introduce you to the US staff.

For another bank HSBC, only 1 Premier status needs to be maintained at 1 jurisdiction. However, they would only introduce you to a limited set of jurisdiction, such as US, UK, HSBC Expat (Jersey) so you can't request a Developing Country and maintain a super low minimum balance for global premier status.